# CRC32 String Comparison of two files that might be identical but not sure

Tags: file, zip, crc32

I have a question regarding CRC (Checksum Redundancy Check).

If there is a " ***slight*** " change in a file, e.g. just changing one character, will its CRC32 result be affected? Or there's a possibility that two different files have same CRC32 result?

I have two files, which I don't know if they are completely identical, but they have the same CRC32 result.

Your feedback is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: One-byte change will change the CRC, but 4-byte change could possibly preserve the CRC. You can never squizze the file to 4-byte, that would be perfect compression ;) There have to be colisions (same CRCs for different files), the probability is what matters here (use larger CRCs or hashes, like MD5 or SHA to decrease probability of colision)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are guaranteed that if only one byte changes, then the CRC is changed.  In fact, if four bytes in a row are changed, or any contiguous 32 bits are changed (i.e. the first and last of the 32 bits are flipped and any subset in between are flipped), then you are guaranteed that the CRC will be changed.

This burst detection capability of CRCs makes them important for transmission and storage applications where burst errors are common.

For a burst one bit longer, interestingly there is only *one* 33-bit pattern that will leave the CRC unchanged.  So nearly all 33-bit contiguous errors will also be detected.

For more bits flipped, or in more dispersed locations, you can arrive back at the original CRC.  Though at a low probability unless the flips are carefully crafted.  You can look at my [`spoof.c`](https://github.com/madler/spoof) program, which given a set of locations to flip in a message and a desired CRC will tell you which of those locations to flip to get the desired CRC.

The linear property of CRCs makes this relatively easy to do.  In addition to simply more bits, this is the reason to have cryptographic hash functions like SHA-2, for which there is no known approach to crafting a message to get a desired signature.

Comment: I assume you come from a communication engineering background. Very well explained.

Comment: @Alana Ref. [Alder-32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adler-32) and associated links.